# get information on attachments to use in the output like file size

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to translate a link like <a ref="123.pdf"> to a link where the filesize is present, like <a ref="123.pdf" size="22Kb">.
The pdf's are present in the folder that contains the inputfile.
Is there a way to do that with xslt 2.0?
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can use the commercial editions (i.e. PE or EE) of Saxon 9 or any other XSLT 2.0 processor that supports the [EXPath file module](http://expath.org/spec/file#pr.size) you can use it as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:file="http://expath.org/ns/file"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs file"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a/@href[file:exists(resolve-uri(., base-uri()))]">
        <xsl:copy/>
        <xsl:attribute name="size" select="concat(file:size(resolve-uri(., base-uri())) idiv 1024, 'KB')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using Saxon that transforms

```
<root>
    <a href="test2016082601.pdf">doc</a>
</root>
```

into

```
<root>
    <a href="test2016082601.pdf" size="141KB">doc</a>
</root>
```

Comment: Sir, getting error 'XPST0017: XSLT Pattern syntax error at char 47 on line 17 in {...s(resolve-uri(., base-uri()...}: Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {http://expath.org/ns/file}exists()'  in saxon9he. and one more error 'XPST0017: XPath syntax error at char 45 on line 19 in {...-uri(., base-uri())) idiv 1...}: Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {http://expath.org/ns/file}size()'. Please can you suggest.

Comment: @RudramuniTP, as clearly said in the beginning of the answer with "commercial editions (i.e. PE or EE) of Saxon 9", the EXPath file module is only supported in the PE and EE editions of Saxon, meaning it is  not supported in the HE edition. So I am afraid I don't have a solution with pure XSLT 2.0, and I don't know of an open source XSLT 2.0 processor supporting EXPath `file:exists()/size()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, plus one, for the nice method to handle the filenames, size of the other document formats like PDF.

Comment: Thanks again, Martin. I work with the PE edition, so this works fine.